# How do I create a task in Task Scheduler with C++

Tags: c++, batch-file, taskmanager

I want to create a program so that what I say, "Add Task." it asks me all the variables like, "task name" and the others.

I then use the system() to use the following command:

schtasks /create /tn TaskName /tr TaskRun /sc schedule /mo modifier

How do I use C++ variables in the system() command?

or, if you have a better way to do this, let me know.

Thanks for your help. 
-Chris

Comment: You need to learn how to concatenate strings.

Comment: A better way: Find the corresponding Windows API function instead of using `system()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Task Scheduler API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383608%28v=vs.85%29). It comes in two versions:

- [Task Scheduler 1.0 Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383581%28v=vs.85%29) - Available for development in C++.
- [Task Scheduler 2.0 Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383600%28v=vs.85%29)  - Available for development in C++ and scripting environments.

Also, from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), take note of the environments supported by each API.

> The Task Scheduler requires the following operating systems.
>
> - Task Scheduler 1.0: Client requires Windows Vista, Windows XP, Windows 2000 Professional, Windows Me, or Windows 98. Server requires
>     Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2003 or Windows 2000 Server.
> - Task Scheduler 2.0: Client requires Windows Vista. Server requires Windows Server 2008.